# Disk Boot Failure. Mbr Problem?

Tags: boot, mbr

My hard disk is 80 gb ide.When i use the hard disk as the data storage only it shows full 80 gb, and am able to store data properly,except for the pc slows down a bit when this particular hard disk is connected.The main problem is i am not able to boot from this hard disk when i install the operating system winxp on this 80 gb ide.It says boot failure. I tried fixmbr, fixboot & formatting,but nothing else.Can anybody figure out what could be the problem of is it my hard disk has gone bad.Pls help me on this and thanx for replying.

Comment: When you're installing XP, are you doing a full NTFS format, or just leaving the drive intact?  Even if you've been doing a quick NTFS format, you might try doing a full one just to make sure.

Answer (score 1):

Poor performance and a strange behavior of an IDE disk may be related
to the master/slave jumper, which should be properly configured
on the disk itself.

For example, if you have an IDE disk and a CD/DVD connected to the
same IDE cable, the IDE disk should be set as the master device and
the CD/DVD as the slave device.

If the IDE disk is the only device connected to the IDE bus,
it should be configured as CS (cable select).

The exact position of the master/slave jumper is vendor-specific and
you need to check carefully the label on the disk for detailed
information about how to set the master/slave jumper.

Comment: I had a drive that just like this that wouldn't boot, and fixing the jumpers solved the problem. Thanks.